# Using scala and lift, how can I do efficient filtering operations on documents in a collection of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, scala, lift, database

I have a User collection in mongodb and am using lift/scala to do User.findAll operations and retrieve the number of users that were created within certain time frames. I am taking advantage of the getTime method of an objectId, however I need to apply a few methods and multiply to get the string that is stored in each document, convert it back to an objectID and convert to seconds from milliseconds. This is the line of code for users created in the last hour:
val users = User.findAll.filter{ u:User => ((((ObjectId.massageToObjectId(u._id)).getTime)/ 1000) <= 3600)}.length

I need to find a way to do this inside the database as opposed to getting all the data into memory and then filtering it with the function. In the past I have used queryBuilder in ways like this to accomplish the same goal but in this case I had no other methods of calculations to apply to the value from the document:
val qry1 = QueryBuilder.start("numberOfFriends").greaterThan(0).get
var oneplus:List[User] =  User.findAll{qry1}

I also am aware of methods like this:
User.findAll(("name" -> "joe") ~ ("age" -> 27))

And I know that findall can take in many other things like a DBObject called sort. But i am unfamiliar with how to use that.

If anyone knows how to manipulate one of these methods or can suggest another it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-Ronnie

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at Foursquare's Rogue. It's a very nice way to query MongoDB and it is type-safe!

Here is how your query would be like:

```
// usage
val d1 = new DateTime(2010, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC)
val users = User where (_._id after d1) count()
```